# Just want confirmation this is a scam

Tags: united-states, credit-card, scams

I recently posted on fb in a group that helps people out, basically people donate to you for whatever you need, food, rent, etc.
I feel like this is a scam, but am a little unsure
So, this woman reached out, and offered to help pay off my credit card, as thats what I had posted about, she's been very nice, normally you can spot a scammer by how they type, but she has very good English, and honestly talks like everyone else I know, using "lol" and stuff like that, her fb seems real, lots of pictures, and a few public posts, such as a birthday fundraiser and all, she wants to give me her account and routing numbers so I can pay off the credit card, she did ask me to buy a steam gift card for "her nephew" which was the first red flag I've seen, so I was thinking it'd be like a "I help you, you help me, we both win" thing, she's not pushy or blowing my phone up or anything, as scammers normally do to people, it seems like a "trust building scam" I recently heard about, but wanted other opinions to be dure

Comment: Yes, it's a scam. It's unlikely the account number she's giving you is hers, which is why she doesn't want to be associated with any withdrawal from the account. (Assuming the bank even *allows* a withdrawal.) She gets the gift card paid for by the real owner of the account, and you never hear from your "benefactor" again.

Comment: Exactly what @chepner said above. Your gut instinct is right, be thankful you caught on before you gave anything to her! Because you would never see it again...

Comment: I just went ahead and blocked and reported her, thank you!

Comment: Someone who wants to actually give you money would simply *give you money*, not talk about *their* bank account, let alone 'steam gift cards' !

Answer (score 12):

Of course it's a scam. Anytime someone needs you to get them a gift card it's a scam. Why would someone be willing to give you money but then want you to purchase a gift card for them? It would be far easier to just give you money and buy their own gift card if this was a legit scenario.